# Python excersise gives wrong answers

Tags: python

Question here and my try below, cant complete no matter how I try.

> N baskets are lined up, numbered 1 . . . N from left to right. The basket number i contains Ki
> apples. John and Mary want to draw a line between two baskets, and then John would get all
> the baskets to the left of the line and Mary all the baskets to the right of the line. Help them
> draw the line to divide the apples as equally as possible!
> Input. The first line of the file jagasis.txt contains N, the number of baskets (2 ≤ N ≤
> 1 000 000). Each of the following N lines contains an integer Ki
> : the number of apples in basket
> number i (1 ≤ i ≤ N, 0 ≤ Ki ≤ 10 000).

> **Output**.
> The only line of the file jagaval.txt should contain a single integer: the number
> of the basket to the right of which the line should be drawn, so that the absolute value of the
> difference between the number of apples John gets, and the number of apples Mary gets, would
> be as small as possible. If there are multiple possible answers, output any one of them.

> **Example.**

> jagasis.txt

7
4
2
10
2
9
3
7

> 

jagaval.txt

> 

4

> ```
> When the line is drawn between the fourth and the fifth basket, John gets 4 + 2 + 10 + 2 = 18
> ```

apples and Mary gets 9 + 3 + 7 = 19 apples. The difference between these numbers is 1, which
is the smallest possible

Here is my code, but its not working for some reason:

```
f = open("jagasis.txt")
inputs = []
for line in f.read().split():
    inputs.append(int(line))
n=[]
location=[]
for x in range(inputs[0]):
    n = inputs[1:]
    m = n[:]
    del n[:x]
    m = set(m) - set(n)
    jagamine=sum(m)/sum(n)
    location.append(jagamine)
p=min(location, key=lambda x:abs(x-1))
uu = location.index(p)
print(location)
f = open("jagaval.txt", "w")
f.write(str(uu))
```

Comment: Please do not answer this before Monday, October 21. This is a task from an ongoing programming contest and posting such questions is explicitly forbidden by contest rules.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to use `set()`. You should just sum the numbers before and after the dividing lines.

You should put the number of apples in a separate list from the number of baskets, so you don't have to keep skipping the first element of the list. And you don't need to make a copy and then delete things, use slices of the original list.

```
with open("jagasis.txt") as f:
    count = int(f.readline().strip())
    baskets = [int(strip(x)) for x in f]
sums = []
for x in range(1, count-1):
    left = sum(baskets[:x])
    right = sum(baskets[x:])
    sums.append(abs(left - right))
result = index(min(sums)) + 1
with open("jagaval.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(str(result))
```

This is not the most efficient algorithm, this is `O(n**2)`. A more efficient algorithm realizes that whenever you move the dividing line to the right, the element at the dividing line is added to the left sum and subtracted from the right sum. So if this is a coding competition, you should use that algorithm or you'll probably fail due to exceeding the time limit.

Answer (score 0):

I just would like to add, that it would be nice if you've added what isn't working for you next time, as often many things may not "be working". Cheers.

Comment: I believe is not an answer - please put such messages into comments

Comment: Thanks for kindly reminder, will remember that for my future activity here.